# Reading JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, complextype

```
{"items":[
{
"name":"xyz",
"traits":["a","b","c","d"],    
"specialities":["a","b","c","d"]
},
{
"name":"abc",
"traits":["a","b","c","d"],    
"specialities":["a","b","c","d"]
}
]}
```

How do I read `traits` and `specialities` ... `items->traits` and `items->traits[0]` doesnt seem to work ! 
Guide me through it please

`$data=json_decode($json);
foreach($data->items as $playerdata)
{
/*
I tried 
$traits=$playerdata->traits;
and 
$traits=$playerdata->traits[0];
and
$traits=$playerdata[0]->traits (althought i dont know why)
*/
}`

I want to store all the values inside `traits` and `specialities` inside a `$traits` and `$specialities` respectively

P.S: Please ignore syntactical errors.. i hope you get the general gist

Comment: By the way, that is not valid json, the first key should be quoted. If this is really your string, `json_decode` will not work.

Comment: it was a typo and I  thought it was fairly obvious ...

Comment: How is that obvious?

Comment: oops sorry here you go :) Thank you for mentioning that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use json_decode() function,

```
$my_object = json_decode($json_string);
```

then you should be able to access it as you normaly do with objects

this is an example of how you should do it

```
<?php

$json = '{"items":[ { "name":"xyz", "traits":["a","b","c","d"],    "specialities":["a","b","c","d"] }, { "name":"abc", "traits":["a","b","c","d"],    "specialities":["a","b","c","d"] } ]}';

$my_object = json_decode($json);

var_export($my_object->items[0]->name);
```

and this is how you can access traits and specialities

```
$traits = [];
$specialities = [];

echo "the traits are:\n";
foreach($my_object->items as $item)
{
    var_dump($item->traits);
    $traits[] = $item->traits;
    echo "\n";
}

echo "\n\n";
echo "the specialities are:\n";
foreach($my_object->items as $item)
{
    var_dump($item->specialities);
    $specialities[] = $item->specialities;
    echo "\n";
}
```

from `var_dump` you can see that `traits` and `specialities` are both arrays, then you can simply access them as array, or write a function that accept an array and return wathever you are looking for.

Comment: assume i decode it to `$data` .. `$data[items][$i][traits]` ??

Comment: @MageshKumaar `$data->items[$i]->traits`

Comment: `foreach ($data->items as $playerdata)` .. this is my foreach statement .. inside it i tried `$traits=$playerdata->$traits` and `$traits=$playerdata->traits[0]`

Comment: can you provide your full foreach, because i can't understand what are you trying to access?

Comment: Yes i have provided it:) Thanks

Comment: @MageshKumaar see my edits on how to access traits and specialities

Comment: @MageshKumaar don't forget to mark the question as an answer if it help's you ;)

Comment: No dude .. its not working .. am guessing its because the objects inside the traits doesnt have a value .. its printing all the values abcd 4 times ?

Comment: @MageshKumaar traits and specialialities they both have the same values in your json, that's way you get abcd 2 times, if you just want to get the value of traits and specialities and store them then you will not need to use a foreach

Comment: They are different.. for simple represenation .. i replaced them

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json_decode` function from php and decode you string. Then you have an array and you can access it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Okay .. so how will it work ..assume i decode it to `$data` .. `$data[items][traits]`?

Comment: var_dump your decoded array and then you see how. I think first you have to iterate over your items

Comment: yeah..I realized that .. so its `$data["items"][$i]["traits"]` ??

Comment: `foreach ($data->items as $playerdata)` this is my foreach .. now how do I access that I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$d = '{"items":[
{
"name":"xyz",
"traits":["a","b","c","d"],    
"specialities":["a","b","c","d"]
},
{
"name":"abc",
"traits":["a","b","c","d"],    
"specialities":["a","b","c","d"]
}
]}';

$h = json_decode($d);

foreach($h->items as $i){
    $traits[] = $i->traits;
    $specialities[] = $i->specialities;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($specialities);
echo "<pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Yes dude .. this works.. but would you be kind enough to tell me how to store $traits[] array as a single value in a table like under traits column

Comment: for display single traits in table column use forloop in array $traits `for($i=0;$i<count($traits);$i++){echo $traits[$i];}`